# Regex for parsing column descriptions

Tags: regex, perl

How do I write a Perl regex for the following data?

```
OID                                                   NOT NULL INTEGER
ACCT_TYPE                                             NOT NULL INTEGER
NAME                                                  NULL     VARCHAR
PAST_DUE_90                                           NULL     INTEGER
```

I'd like to parse it into three separate columns. All whites space are spaces. The fact that the second columns can have two words or one makes it tricky. Note that there are trailing spaces at the end of each line.

The last thing I tried was this:

```
my ($col1, $col2, $col3) = $line =~ /^(\S+)\s+\b(.+) \b(\S+)\s*$/;
```

That regex works here: https://regex101.com/r/6beMrM/1 but when I run it in the actual code the `cols` are `undef`.

**SOLVED**
There was a leading space in each of the file lines that I didn't notice.

Comment: Is the second column always `NULL` or `NOT NULL`?

Comment: I don't know for sure. There are 23 different tables of data. So the solution should be generalized.

Comment: So if the regex works by itself and the actual code does not, why are you showing us the regex instead of your code? [mcve], please.

Comment: It could have been possible that online regex engine was flawed.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that should work:

```
my ($col1, $col2, $col3) = $line =~ /^\s*(\w+)\s+((?:\w+ )?\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*$/;
```

Comment: Hmm, all cols still coming up undef.

Comment: Ah, found the problem. There was a leading white space in each the lines that I didn't notice.

Comment: @StevieD: Just add `\s*` in front of the regex, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern doesn't give `undef` for me but the NULL/NOT NULL part had some whitespace around it.
I slightly changed it and got the desired result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    my ($col1, $col2, $col3) = $line =~ /^\s*(\S+)\s+(.+?)\s+(\S+)\s*$/;
    print "col1: [$col1], col2: [$col2], col3: [$col3]\n";
}

__DATA__
OID                                                   NOT NULL INTEGER
ACCT_TYPE                                             NOT NULL INTEGER
NAME                                                  NULL     VARCHAR
PAST_DUE_90                                           NULL     INTEGER
```

**Output:**

```
col1: [OID], col2: [NOT NULL], col3: [INTEGER]
col1: [ACCT_TYPE], col2: [NOT NULL], col3: [INTEGER]
col1: [NAME], col2: [NULL], col3: [VARCHAR]
col1: [PAST_DUE_90], col2: [NULL], col3: [INTEGER]
```

**Just for reference: your pattern gave:**

```
col1: [OID], col2: [NOT NULL], col3: [INTEGER]
col1: [ACCT_TYPE], col2: [NOT NULL], col3: [INTEGER]
col1: [NAME], col2: [NULL    ], col3: [VARCHAR]
col1: [PAST_DUE_90], col2: [NULL    ], col3: [INTEGER]
```